# It made or it was made

Tags: past-tense

> He was not in there when the song made.
> He was not in there when the song was made.

Above the two sentences which one seems more appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

"He was not in there when the song was made." Is better because the second clause (the song was made) is a passive sentence; the song was made, the song (being the subject) did not do or preform any action, therefore using 'made' would not be appropriate; rather we use 'was made' because it is passive.

If the sentence was active, we could (for example) say 'The song made me feel better' (or something like that).

Also, I would not use "in there"; instead, I would simply use "there".

With the 'in', 'in there' becomes a prepositional phrase, while 'there' alone is an adverb and sounds better as the prepositional phrase (in there) does not add any more meaning to the sentence than 'there'.

Eg.  "He was not there when the song was made".

Answer (score 0):

The second one is correct (asterisk * used to mark incorrect usage):

> He was not in there when the song *made.
>
> He was not in there when the song was made.

“Make” (in the sense of “create”) is a **transitive** verb. It needs a subject (the maker) and an object (the product).

Correct:

> I made the song.

Grammatically correct, but semantically unlikely:

> The song made me.

Incorrect:

> I *made.
>
> The song *made.

You can leave out the subject of a transitive verb by changing to the **passive** form.

Correct:

> The song was made.

Correct, if unusual:

> I was made.

(This would make sense as a religious statement, perhaps—“I was made by God”. Or from an artificial being in science fiction—“I was made in a laboratory”. Or as a statement of purpose—“I was made for loving you, baby”.)